# Symfony2 mapping between 3 entities

Tags: database, symfony, mapping, associations

I have three entities : **Event**, **Photo** and **User**.

[image]

**Three main relations :**

- An Event has 0 or more photos (blue relation, OneToMany)
- An Event has been created by one photo, which I call the firstPhoto (red relation,
  OneToOne)
- A user can create 0 or more photos (violet relation,
  OneToMany)

What I want is **to map the relation between an Event and the User who created it**, without adding or changing my database. It means the user that created the firstPhoto of the Event.

I'm not looking for a SQL query which I succed to do but really a mapping in my User.php Entity.

`$user->getEvents()` would give the events the user created.

I can't success to do so... any idea ? Am I obliged to add or change something in my database ?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways of doing that:

1) make a named native query http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#named-native-query

2) write something like

```
public function getEvents()
{
     $res = array();
     $photos = $this->getPhotos();
     foreach($photos as $photo) {
         $res[] = $photo->getEvent();
     }

     return $res;
}
```

Comment: $photo->getEvent(); would give the Event the photo is in and not necessarily the one that has been created by the photo (if there is one)

Comment: `$photo->getEvent()` should return OneToOne relation to event. If it's nullable you can add a condition to filter not nulls.